# Error - show json data into tableview swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to display some data into a `UITableView`, but the data is not shown in the `UITableView`. The data is formatted in JSON.

The code I'm writing to display into the `UITableView` is this:

```
var mainList:[[String:AnyObject]] = []

@IBOutlet var listCountriesTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.listCountriesTableView.dataSource = self
    self.listCountriesTableView.delegate = self

    let urlPath = "http://data.okfn.org/data/core/country-codes/r/country-codes.json"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
        } else {
            do {
                let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                for country in jsonResult {
                    let countryName = country["name"]!
                    let countryDial = country["Dial"]!
                    let nameDial = ["name":countryName, "Dial":countryDial]
                    self.mainList.append(nameDial)

                    print(country["name"]!, country["Dial"]!)
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

}

```
extension ListOfCountriesViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.mainList.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellList = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellListCountries")! as UITableViewCell
    let data = mainList[indexPath.row]
    let countryTableView = data["name"]
    let codeTableView = data["Dial"]
    cellList.textLabel!.text = countryTableView
    cellList.detailTextLabel!.text = codeTableView
    return cellList
}
```

---

The `print(country["name"]!`, `country["Dial"]!)` shows me the correct list of countries and dial code in the debug area, but is not showed in the `UITableView`.

***Debug area*: 
Afghanistan 93
Albania 355
Algeria 213
American Samoa 1-684
Andorra 376
Angola 244
Anguilla 1-264
Antarctica 672
Antigua and Barbuda 1-268
Argentina 54
Armenia 374
Aruba 297**

Anyone knows what is my problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you call `reloadData` anywhere?

Comment: Yea. I put it after "task.resume()". Also, the result give me these 2 errors in the "cellList.textLabel!.text" --> Cannot assign value of type 'AnyObject?' to type 'String?'

Answer (score 0):

Your data are loaded async. When they ready UITableView is already shown. Thats why you should reload it. Call:

```
[self.listCountriesTableView reloadData];
```

or

```
self.listCountriesTableView.reloadData()
```

just after you parse data.

Comment: Great. I put it after "task.resume()". Also, the result give me these 2 errors in "cellList.textLabel!.text = countryTableView" and "cellList.detailTextLabel!.text = codeTableVie" ---> Cannot assign value of type 'AnyObject?' to type 'String?

Comment: @JoshB where do you initialise `self.mainList`?. Put tableview update code after `for {...}` loop.

Comment: I called a `var mainList:[[String:AnyObject]] = []` at the beginning of the code, and then I add items with `.append` in the code `for {...}`

Comment: ... so, the tableView shows me data but just from the predefined style (literally: "Title") instead of the data from JSON